# Is There a way to add Wii Points after 26 march?

Tags: nintendo-wii, nintendo-eshop

Because i want to add Wii Points after 26 march.
Is There bug to add them?

Comment: From what source do you want to add them?

Comment: Credit card or Wii points giftcard

Comment: I don't think there will be any new games in the shop after that date, so the only reason to do that would be if you bought a used Wii after that date.

Comment: Yeah, i know that. I wanted to buy some virtual console and Wiiware games.

Comment: Then do it now.

Comment: But i wanted to ADD WII POINTS. NOT to USE them.

Comment: You do realize that the Wii store is shutting down next year, right? At which point any points you haven't spent, or apps you bought and haven't redownloaded, are gone. What is your future plan?

Comment: I know about that! I just want to know is There a way to add Wii Points while my local Store still sell Wii Giftcards!

Comment: Yes, use them until it deactivates that functionality. Then you have a few months to spend them.

Comment: Again. I WANT TO ADD THEM!

Comment: But why would you want to have points sitting around that do nothing because you don't use them? Also, in the last message I meant "add the points while you still can, then you can spend them for a few months.

Comment: We're just having trouble understanding your goal here; there seems to be very little purpose in adding points, so we want to understand what it is you're doing, and why.  Help us help you.

Comment: Sorry for not responding. In my Time zone There was night, so i was sleeping. Ok. Fabian, i want to add them, and use them for buying virtual console games. Frank, i want to add them Because i have buyed used Wii that doesnt have any Wii Points. I need our help Because i want to add them. Because after 26 march There is no add Wii Points button. So i wanna know is There is a way to add them.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Wii Points is digital currency for the Wii.  They are shutting down the option to buy them after March 26, which has already passed.

There is no way to get points anymore.  What about possible bugs?  Well, the Wii has been around for **twelve** years.  Whatever bug that existed, people either have fixed it, or the system is so old nobody cares about finding new ones.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not do that. Try using the Wii u if you want the virtual console, or if you want a WiiWare game maybe there is a rom online